# magento controller not found

Tags: magento, controller, adminhtml

I have set up a controller in my module to add an order export tab to my installation:

in config.xml:

```
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <orderexport>abc_Orderexport_index2</orderexport>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <orderexport>
                    <file>orderexport.xml</file>
                </orderexport>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </admin>
```

in adminhtml.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <sales>
            <children>
                <orderexport>
                    <title>Order Export</title>
                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/index2</action>
                </orderexport>
            </children>
        </sales>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <sales>
                        <children>
                            <orderexport>
                                <title>Order Export</title>
                                <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            </orderexport>
                        </children>
                    </sales>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

and in the controllers/Adminhtml/Index2Controller.php file

```
class abc_Orderexport_Adminhtml_Index2Controller extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
         $this->loadLayout();
         $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

However with all this done, whenever I click on the button "Order Export" it redirects me to the 404 page. That means that Magento cannot find the controller but idk why.

When i rename the controller everywhere from index2 into index (Index2Controller.php to IndexController.php) I am not getting redirected to the 404 page, HOWEVER the Dashboard of the admin panel just reloads.

I really don't know where my error is and Im happy for any hints into the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you have to fix:

1. in `config.xml`: you have to say that your module should be use in the adminhtml area, and you have to respect the CamelCase, here is how it should look like:

   ```
   <admin>
       <routers>
           <adminhtml>
               <args>
                   <modules>
                       <Abc_Orderexport after="Mage_Adminhtml">Abc_Orderexport_Adminhtml</Abc_Orderexport>
                   </modules>
               </args>
           </adminhtml>
       </routers>
   </admin>
   ```
2. in your controller, again, you must respect CamelCase, i.e. the class name is `Abc_Orderexport_Adminhtml_Index2Controller`

All this is assuming your folder structure is:

```
app/
  code/
     local/
        Abc/
          Orderexport/
               controllers/
                     Adminhtml/
                          Index2Controller.php
               etc/
                 config.xml
                 adminhtml.xml
```

, exactly, upper/lower case is important

Comment: Thank you this works, however the page i am getting is empty. as you can see i have a layout update for the module, shouldnt the .xml and .phtml file be called when i use 

 public function indexAction()
    {
         $this->loadLayout();
         $this->renderLayout();
    }

in the controller?

this is my xml file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <orderexport_index2_index>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="page/html" name="orderexport" template="orderexport.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </orderexport_index2_index>
</layout>

Comment: @Tom your question was about the controller not found, which you say now that my answer has solved: I'd appreciate then if you'd upvote and mark it as correct. Doing so will encourage me and others to help you again with your next question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following code and make sure that you module class name and folder structure must be in standard magento
extension structure. config.xml

```html
 <admin>
        <routers>
  <orderexport>
      <use>admin</use>
          <args>
              <modules>
                  <orderexport>Abc_Orderexport_Index2</orderexport>
    <frontName>orderexport</frontName>
              </modules>
          </args>
  <orderexport>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <orderexport>
                    <file>orderexport.xml</file>
                </orderexport>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </admin>
```